# HTML Comments in Document examples are there any rules to their use?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-editor

I have noticed that some of the examples in documents have included HTML style comment blocks within the example content

```
<!---- Something to say ----!>
```

The content of the comments does not appear on the example or in the review history, and is only viewable when you edit the example. I personally think this would be a great way to include relevant information for people that edit the example, but would be of no use to those just reading the example.

The question is.

Is this a legitimate method of communication within a Document example, or a loop hole soon to be plugged?

If acceptable what are the rules concerning the content of hidden content, above the given (ie no novels, no ownership claims, no abuse, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's neither. It's just something that some people like to do if they deem it necessary, and has been known for years in all places that allow some HTML in the Markdown. What you're really doing is just creating HTML that the system deems invalid (not allowed to be used) and strips out of the final rendered post, so it never appears. Technically, you don't have to use HTML comment syntax - you can use any syntax that *looks* like HTML and would cause the system to strip it out, such as:

```
<As long as the long block of text is between angled brackets it won't show up.>
```

We have no plans to actually strip this content out of the source when it's submitted, as that could cause a lot of problems. Not everyone realizes their HTML can't be used, or that they need to format it correctly as code when it's demonstrating something. It's nice to be able to go edit and still have it there, rather than having to type it or go find it again later when you notice it's missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried the `<tag content>` syntax on a document and it displayed normally with the greater and less than being displayed as well. Though the method is just a side point, just thought I would point it out.